# regex positioning confusion

Tags: python, regex

I have a question about the positioning of the "do not include operator in regex in python" shown below

```
[^]
```

If I have the following expression

```
print(re.findall(r'^[^_][-\w\d]+[^:/)]$',x))
```

does it matter where i place [^:/)] or will it only exclude : and / at the end of the string since i placed it at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `$` at the end of your regular expression you've anchored the `[^:/)]` character group to only match at the end of the string. Any matches **must** end with `[^:/)]`.

Comment: I see, so if I did not include the beginning ^ and end $, the "do not include operator [^]" would not count the string regardless of where the : and / are, not only at the end?

Comment: No, @aaron. A character class, your `[^:/)]`, can appear any place an individual character can appear. The `^` modifier at the start of the character class simply inverts the class of characters matched. It does not affect where in the string the character class matches. In other words, `[:/)]` will match any of those three characters at the position where the character class appears. Whereas `[^:/)]` matches any character other than those three chars in the same position.

Comment: It's for the web, but I know these docs are reliable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions